# Cypress && Angular - get selector from href inside Ngfor

Tags: angular, cypress, e2e

I have a side navigation bar and I'm trying to make a test to click on a link and redirect to the correspondent page.

The selector is inside  element that is inside a ngFor loop.

```
     <ng-container *ngFor="let item of listItems">
        <li>
            <a [data-test]="item.routerLink"></a>
        </li>
    </ng-container>
```

I already try using a[href] but had no success.

```
    it('should redirect user to welcome', () => {
        cy.getBySelector('a[href*="/welcome"]').click();
    });
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend creating a unique `id` for each item making use of the `index`, and then you can select it with Cypress like the following:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of listItems; let i = index">
 <li>
   <a [attr.cy-data]="'myLink-' + i" [data-test]="item.routerLink"></a>
 </li>
</ng-container>
```

```js
// * specify the index, here I'm using index 2, "select the 3rd link"
cy.get("[data-cy='myLink-2']").click();
```